# ReadObject Method

Tags: java, exception, objectinputstream

anyway to check if method readObject of class ObjectInputStream has finished reading file other than catching its thrown exceptions?

and if no. how can I make outNewmast.writeObject(accountRecord); statement reached in this case?

```
// read oldmast.ser
    try {
        while (true) {
            accountRecord = (AccountRecord) inOldmast.readObject();
            //read trans.ser
            while (true) {
                transactionRecord = (TransactionRecord) inTrans.readObject();
                if (transactionRecord.getAccountNumber() == accountRecord.getAccount()) {
                    accountRecord.combine(transactionRecord);
                }//end if
            }//end inner while
            outNewmast.writeObject(accountRecord);
        }//end while
    }//end try 
    catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
        System.err.println("Error reading file.");
        System.exit(1);
    }//end catch         
    catch (IOException e) {
        System.err.println("Error reading file.");
        System.exit(1);
    }//end catch
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best idea would be to serialize the number of elements beforehand, so you could just do:

```
cnt = file.readInt();
for (int i=0;i<cnt;i++) {
   file.readObject();
}
```

The method proposed by @ChrisCooper is not reliable, as stated in documentation. Some streams don't implement it, or return approximate result (in theory, it can even return 0 when there is still some data. Example - network stream).

Therefore, looking at same documentation, we find this particular block:

> Any attempt to read object data which exceeds the boundaries of the
>   custom data written by the corresponding writeObject method will cause
>   an OptionalDataException to be thrown with an eof field value of true.
>   Non-object reads which exceed the end of the allotted data will
>   reflect the end of data in the same way that they would indicate the
>   end of the stream: bytewise reads will return -1 as the byte read or
>   number of bytes read, and primitive reads will throw EOFExceptions. If
>   there is no corresponding writeObject method, then the end of default
>   serialized data marks the end of the allotted data.

So, the best idea would be to catch an `OptionalDataException` and check it's `eof` field for `true`.

And to digest the answer even further, here's the method you want:

```
TransactionRecord readRecord(ObjectInputStream stream) throws OptionalDataException, IOException {
    try {
        transactionRecord = (TransactionRecord) stream.readObject();
    } catch (OptionalDataException e) {
        if (e.eof) {
            return null;
        } else {
            throw e;
        }
    }
    return transactionRecord;
}
.....
TransactionRecord record;
while ((record = readRecord(inTrans)) != null) {
    doSomethingWithRecord(record);
}
endOfFile();
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, check the input stream to see if anything more is available:

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/InputStream.html#available()

```
if (inOldmast.available() > 0) {
  // read and process
} else {
  // Close the stream and clean up
}
```